# In python how can I hoist key from a dict without loop?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dict like this:

```
{"father_id":"No.1", "a_have_list":[{"child_id":1},{"child_id":2}]}
```

and I want extract this dict and hoist child id like this:

```
[{"child_id":1, "child_father_id":"No.1"}, {"child_id":2, "child_father_id":"No.1"}]
```

How can I do this pythonic without ugly loop?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `{"father_id": "No.1", "a_have_list": [{"child_id":1}, {"child_id":2}]}`?

Comment: And where does `child_father_id` comes from?

Comment: Also, why would a loop be ugly if what you're trying to do *requires*  iterating over a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to use a loop. You can integrate that loop into a list comprehension:

```
[dict(child, child_father_id=d['father_id']) for child in d['a_have_list']]
```

This creates a copy of each child dictionary, adding in a `father_id` key as you go along.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'father_id':"No.1", 'a_have_list':[{'child_id':1},{'child_id':2}]}
>>> [dict(child, father_id=d['father_id']) for child in d['a_have_list']]
[{'child_id': 1, 'father_id': 'No.1'}, {'child_id': 2, 'father_id': 'No.1'}]
```

Comment: Why not `dict(child, father_id=d['father_id'])`? Doesn't seem necessary to expand the dict there (especially if the dict have non-string keys).

Comment: @parchment: no reason, other than that I made an assumption that the child could override the new key

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without a loop: you need to operate on each element in turn, so obviously this needs a loop. A list comprehension would be fine:

```
father_id = my_dict['father_id']
[{'child_id': inner_dict['child_id'], 'child_father_id': father_id} for inner_dict in my_dict['a_have_list']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want *explicit* kind of loop (and prefer some fancy-looking list comprehension), and that the actual input is a list of dicts rather than a single dict since that is more likely.

That is, an example input looks like:

```
[{'father_id': 'No.1', 'a_have_list': [{'child_id': 1}, {'child_id': 2}]},
 {'father_id': 'No.2', 'a_have_list': [{'child_id': 3}]}]
```

Then you can combine two list comprehensions to get the desired result:

```
[{'child_id': y['child_id'], 'child_father_id': x['father_id']}
    for x in inp for y in x['a_have_list']]
```

The result being:

```
[{'child_id': 1, 'child_father_id': 'No.1'},
 {'child_id': 2, 'child_father_id': 'No.1'},
 {'child_id': 3, 'child_father_id': 'No.2'}]
```

But you have to decide whether the loop is really that ugly :).